# How can I map the values of two items fetched from APIs?

Tags: reactjs, api, redux, mapping

I'm fetching data from two APIs and getting:
- an array of user objects, each with an ID
- an array of meeting objects, each with an owner id that corresponds with a user id

I want to fetch all this data only once, in my Home component, and render all meetings with their respective owners on the page. It works sometimes, but occasionally it throws a TypeError: Cannot read property 'first_name' of undefined. I assume this is because it's asynchronous, but my action both use the async await syntax and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

actions (fetchUsers looks the same)

```
export const fetchMeetings = () => async dispatch => {
  const response = await api.get('/meetings');
  dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_MEETINGS', payload: response.data });
};
```

in component:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchMeetings();
    this.props.fetchUsers();
  }
...
  const getOwnerName = ownerID => {
    const owner = users.filter(user => user.id === ownerID)[0]
    return `${owner.first_name} ${owner.last_name}`
  }

  const meetingsArray = meetings.map(meeting => 
    <div key={meeting.callid}>
      <Meeting
        name={meeting.name}
        startTime={meeting.start_time}
        endTime={meeting.end_time}
        owner={getOwnerName(meeting.owner)} />
    </div>
  )
```

Comment: Can you console.log your response variable before dispatching the action? Also, what are your using to communicate with your api? Axios? I see you're using api.get("/meetings") but that's not typically a normal object in React.

Comment: Yes, I'm getting the response correctly in fetchMeetings and fetchUsers. I'm using axios - here 'api' is just an import from another file where I've defined my url and a proxy (using a proxy because I was getting a CORS error" like so: 
```
export default axios.create ({
  baseURL: proxyurl + url
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using async/await **inside** `fetchMeetings(...)` method, but that does not affect how this method is run **outside** of the function. Both `fetchMeetings(...)` and `fetchUsers (...)` will still run in `componentDidMount(...)` asynchronously.

I believe this works only when `fetchUsers(...)` finish first. Try this to fix it:

```
async componentDidMount() {
   await this.props.fetchUsers();
   await this.props.fetchMeetings();
}
```

Comment: That sounds like it could be the right solution, but I can't use that syntax. It throws a parsing error: Can not use keyword 'await' outside an async function.

Comment: The fix was missing async keyword, please try now.